# Express Middleware being executed out of order

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning about Express middleware.  I separated my middleware functions into a simple module.  I usually export my modules as an object rather than a function which might be my issue but if so I'd like to know why..  In any case, I'm getting my first middleware function to output before the handler, then the handler, then the first function again.  Can someone explain why this is happening?

Here's my main app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var something = require('./something');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(something.firstMiddle);
app.use(something.lastMiddle);

app.get('/', something.middleHandler, function(req,res){
res.render('index', { title: 'Yo Mama!' });
});


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

and my module something.js

```
module.exports = {
middleHandler: function(req,res,next){
    console.log('In the handler');
    next();
},
firstMiddle: function(req, res, next){
    console.log("In first middle!");
    next();
},
lastMiddle: function(req,res,next){
    console.log('Last middleware');
    next();
}
};
```

It's outputting:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
In first middle!
In the handler
In first middle!
```

Comment: I get `In first middle!Last middlewareIn the handler`

Comment: Not sure why you voted down... I'm still getting the odd result.. the whole purpose of my question is to figure out why I'm getting the stuff out of sequence.

Comment: Because it is not out of sequence. The middlewares will be executed in the order of registration only

Comment: When I run this with the two middleware functions registered in order and the handler in the app.get(), I get 'first', 'last' 'handler', 'first', 'last' - why is it getting executed multiple times?  Second.. the handler is registered with the get.. but the first, last go before the handler.. is that how it works? aside from the multiple execution deal?

Comment: It executes the middleware functions because browser sends a separate request for `favicon.ico`

Comment: So I picked a crappy sample to model after i guess.  The handler gets issued with the get request, and the other two get issued on any request... including the static file gets?  hence two sets of first, last and only one 'handler'.  Thanks